# Is there an elegant and efficient SQL way of listing all substring positions?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, full-text-search

I have a text column in an sql database. My task is to find all occurrences of a given string in the texts, and list the character positions text by text (for backreference later in the application).

I have found examples like [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql-question-how-can-we-find-all-the-occurrences-of-a-text-in-a-string) that solve a similar issue by a while loop. However, I dislike the idea of writing a loop is there exists a slimmer way of doing the same.

I imagine this to work similarly to [STRING_SPLIT in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), although I emphasize I am preferably looking for a MySQL solution. STRING_SPLIT returns a one column table filled with the substrings of the split string. An imaginary ALL_POSITIONS method could return a one column table filled with the starting positions of the matches in the text, or an empty table, if there's no match. Or, for the sake of JOINing, there could be another column for a primary key reference.

So let's take an example table for illustrating my point:

```
|Id|Text                      |
+--+--------------------------+
| 0|This is my teststring     |
| 1|A second teststring       |
```

My dream Pseudo-SQL:

`SELECT ALL_POSITIONS('st', Text, Id) FROM Table;`

Which would yield:

```
|Id|Position|
+--+--------+
| 0|      13|    <- the first 'st' where Id = 0
| 0|      15|    <- the second 'st' where Id = 0 etc.
| 1|      11|
| 1|      13|
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Check this : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41961/how-to-find-all-positions-of-a-string-within-another-string

Comment: It might be possible in but the syntax would be like `SELECT * FROM myfn('<search string>', '<table name>', '<column name>')`. And it _has_ to be a WHILE loop.

Comment: Do you want a MySQL answer, or an SQL Server answer?

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. I removed the conflicting tags, please add only the relevant one.

Comment: You can probably do this with a recursive CTE (MySQL 8+) and the LOCATE function, which accepts an index to start searching from (which would be the index + length of the last found occurrence from a previous iteration of the cte)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a recursive CTE for SQL Server:

```
with cte as (
  select id, charindex('st', text) pos from tablename
  union all
  select t.id, charindex('st', t.text, c.pos + 1) 
  from tablename t inner join cte c
  on c.id = t.id
  where c.pos > 0 and c.pos < len(t.text)
)
select * from cte
where pos > 0
order by id, pos
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce1d8eb5ad5b3b8446c7650683bb7f41).
For MySql 8.0+:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select id, locate('st', text) pos from tablename
  union all
  select t.id, locate('st', t.text, c.pos + 1) 
  from tablename t inner join cte c
  on c.id = t.id
  where c.pos > 0 and c.pos < length(t.text)
)
select * from cte
where pos > 0
order by id, pos
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fr7Qq5ikLBv2wjdEDdshmJ/1).
Results:

```
> id | pos
> -: | --:
>  0 |  14
>  0 |  16
>  1 |  12
>  1 |  14
```